# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib.request'; 'urllib' is not a package

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib, urllib2, urllib3

I have the following code and i tried all i could find on stackoverflow but nothing worked. Here is the code:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt')
counts = dict()
for line in fhand:
    words = line.decode().split()
for word in words:
    counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1
print(counts)
```

And the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib.request'; 'urllib' is not a package

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem. I already had a file that was named urllib.py and that is why the error. Now that i deleted it everything works fine! Hope this answer will help everyone in need.

Answer (score 0):

do you have urllib installed? if not try to install it like this :
pip install urllib3

Comment: In that case the error would look like this: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib.request'`, without phrase `'urllib' is not a package`.

Answer (score 0):

This exact same issue happened to me. After trying and trying, I just ended up rewriting the code and saving the file into a new folder by itself and it ran without any problems.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

re-named my urllib-named file, that helped me too as Dharman stated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The answer is very brief and can be improved by providing more details. It will help others understand.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32382309)

Answer (score 0):

My file name was urllib.py, changed it to workbitch.py and now it works perfectly! ;)

Hope this helps!